# How to use collection_select for a table with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have the following setup:

**Table.rb**

```
has_many: orders
```

**Order.rb**

```
belongs_to: table
```

And the `order` table has a `boolean` value of `finished` and I have this script:

```
collection_select(:order, :table_id, Table.all, :id, :table, prompt: false)
```

what I need to do is only select those tables that have orders where all orders are finished. So

```
if all orders for this table have order.finished == true OR if it doesn't have any orders at all { list that table }
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a method in table.rb which returns those tables who have orders and are finished or those tables who dont have orders.

```
def self.table_with_finished_or_no_orders
  Table.joins("left join orders on orders.table_id=tables.id).where("orders.finished = ? OR orders.table_id is NULL",  true)
end
```

and you will call this method in views like this

```
  collection_select(:order, :table_id, Table.table_with_finished_or_no_orders, :id, :table, prompt: false)
```

i guess my query is according to your requirement.

Comment: This gives me a `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'table.id' in 'on clause': SELECT 'tables'.* FROM 'tables' left join orders on orders.table_id=table.id WHERE (orders.finished = 1 OR orders.table_id is NULL)` maybe I need something else for it?

Comment: table name is plural i used table. updated it tables now. please try

Comment: Actually - there is one more thing, it returns as many tables as there are orders now, is it possible to do this and make it return only distinct tables?

Comment: Try to add .uniq at the end and see. I guess it will return unique records